# Recreating solution file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I need help re-creating a web solution file (at least I think that is what I need). I inherited a web application from another developer that left our company. It was created in Visual Studio 2010 and uses ASP.Net 2.0. There was no solution file, so I created a web application project and manually added all folders and files into my new solution. I did not make any changes to any file in the web application.

When I run the app from within Visual Studio, it starts up to the default page fine, but when I click a link on that same page, I get:

> ```
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found. 
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could     
> have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the  
> following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>
>    Requested URL: /SomeCompany/startProject.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8008
> ```

My original start location: `http://mylocalurl:65212/default.aspx` 
Link on the default page: `http://mylocalurl:65212/SomeCompany/startProject.aspx`

If, after clicking the link and getting the error page, I can remove "`/SomeCompany/`", and successfully get to the page. But I've seen the previous developer run it in Visual Studio and click the exact same link with no problem.

I need it to have the `/SomeCompany/` in the url and work just like the previous developer had it so I can maintain and debug it as needed. What am I doing wrong in re-creating the solution...or is it another setup problem that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Web.config, URL rewriting.  IIS Setup?

Comment: I've checked the web.config and there is no url rewriting. It is being run from Visual Studio, using file system, so there should not be any IIS setup should there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have probably just used file -> open web site. It probably is not a Web Application. Visual Studio has multiple types of web projects. Visual Studio will create a solution for you that you can save after you open the website.

[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that and it opens without giving me the /SomeCompany/ that I am looking for.

Comment: One thing I that I might have figured out. I am using Visual Studio 2013 (I missed saying that in my original post). VS 2013 opens it up without the /SomeCompany/ structure, but when I go to my old laptop, which has VS 2010, I can open it and it has the structure I want. Is there something in VS 2013 that I need to configure to get it to open the same as when in VS 2010?

Comment: Try creating a web application in IIS under /SomeCompany/ then open website from IIS instead of file system